# fwrite to write different data (C Programming)

Tags: c

**Introduction**

Hello! This is a small C project that saves the user's first name, last name and prints it out.

It would work without problems when you enter the first user.
However, when you add another user, the program crashes.

---

**Problem**

- crashes when you add a second user

---

**Questions**

- does `fwrite` save data as two different elements when I add a second user?
  **For example:**

  ---

  **First User:**
  First Name: John
  Last Name: Lemon
  **Second User:**
  First Name: James
  Last Name: Bond

---

- Else if it doesn't, how do I separate the data's from each other?

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>

char user[]={"user.txt"};

struct user
{
    char firstname[10];
    char lastname[10];
};

void viewdata ()
{
    char input[20];

    FILE *fp;

    struct user u1;

    fp = fopen(user,"rb");

    fread(&u1,sizeof(u1),1,fp);

    printf("Please enter user first name you wish to search: ");
    scanf("%s",&input);

    if ((strcmp(input,u1.firstname)==0))
    {
        printf("\nUser First Name: %s",u1.firstname);
        printf("\nUser Last Name: %s\n\n",u1.lastname);
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    else
        printf("\nNot found!\n\n");
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        main();
};

void enterdata ()
{
    char choice;

    FILE *fp;

    struct user u1;

    printf("\nPlease enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s",&u1.firstname);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nPlease enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s",&u1.lastname);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nConfirm? (Y/N): ");
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
    {
        fp=fopen(user,"a");
        fwrite(&u1,sizeof(u1),1,fp);
        fclose(fp);
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    else
        printf("\nData has not been saved!");
        system("pause");
        main();
};

int main ()
{
    int choice;

    printf("\n1. Enter data\n");
    printf("\n2. View data\n");

    printf("\n\nPlease select an option: ");

    scanf("%d",&choice);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        enterdata();
    }
    else if (choice == 2);
    {
        system("cls");
        viewdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you save the data and load it is different.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so if I save it with fwrite, I need to read it with fread?

Comment: @sugar, yes, that is correct.

Comment: @RSahu if so, does `fwrite` save the second user as a separate element?

Comment: @sugar, it should since you are opening the file in append mode.

Comment: Don't call `main`. If you want a loop, write one.

Comment: this line: `else if (choice == 2);` is not correct.  Strongly suggest removing the trailing semicolon `;`.

Comment: this line: `};` is not correct.  Strongly suggest removing the trailing semicolon `;`.

Comment: when calling system functions (fopen, fread, scanf, etc) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, using the `%s` format specifier, always include a 'max characters' modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, to 1) allow room for the (automatically added) trailing NUL byte 2) to avoid a input buffer overrun, as that would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: NEVER call main()`,  Suggest using a loop to re-execute code

Comment: in the calls to `system()`, the commands `cls` and `pause` are not portable.  In general, those commands are only recognized in a `windows` OS environment.  The OPs question does not specify a 'windows' environment.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%c",&choice);` will not work as expected.  This is because the preceeding call to `scanf()` will have left the 'newline' sequence in the stdin stream and `%c` will not skip over the 'newline' sequence (white space) so what will be input is the first character of the newline sequence.  This now leaves a character 'Y' and a second newline sequence in the stdin stream.  Then the subsequent callt to `scanf()` to get the first name will only input the 'Y'.   You need to clean out stdin before trying to read the 'Y;.

Comment: the `fflush()` function is only defined for output streams.  stdin is NOT a output stream.  so it will not work as the posted code is expecting.

Comment: in function: `main()` the testing of the variable 'choice' would be much clearer if a `switch()` statement were used, then used a 'default' case when the user did not input a 1 or 2.

Comment: the displayed menu and the associated code needs a third valid choice so the user can gracefully exit the program without having to use a `^C` (or similar) key stroke sequence.

Comment: this line: `if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')` is not a good method for checking the value of a user input.   Suggest: if( 'y' == tolower(choice) )`  Note: the `tolower()` is one of the many resources available when the statement: `#include <ctype.h>` is at the beginning of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [If the file is successfully opened, the function returns a pointer to a FILE object that can be used to identify the stream on future operations.
>   Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

You should take care to check whether you were able to open the file successfully once you call `fopen()` by checking `fp == NULL` and erroring out if so. This will prevent the crash.

You're also reading it the wrong way. If you use `fwrite`, make sure to use `fread`.

`fscanf(fp,"%s %s",&u1.firstname,&u1.lastname); // wrong`

Although I strongly advise on not storing binary data and retrieving them from a file, you should be doing something like this instead.

`fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp);`

Comment: even when saving with `fwrite` and reading with `fread`, I still can't read the second user data. It saves into my text file, but my program can't search for the data.

Comment: @sugar You haven't written any code to do any searching.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isn't `void viewdata()` the code to search for `u1.firstname` and print out `u1.firstname` and `u1.lastname` if it matches with `input`?

Comment: @sugar No, since it only calls `fread` once. Also, you call `fopen` but not `fclose`, and you assume the `fopen` succeeded without checking. All things that are not good.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so how do I correct this? sorry, I don't really follow for the `fread`.

Comment: @sugar Start by writing out the algorithm you want your code to execute. Think through what it has to do and in what order. Include checks at critical steps to make sure things are going as planned (for example, after trying to open the file, check if it's open). Then, and only then, try to write code to execute the algorithm you documented. Also, don't jump around. If you want to repeat, use a loop.

Comment: @sugar, my answer just fixes the crash you were seeing. As DavidSchwartz said in his comment I noticed that you'll have to write a loop to print your names. There are tons of things that can go wrong in your code. From overwriting buffers to NULL pointers which will lead to a crash. Welcome to programming in C!